# how to apply ternary operator on a single button click event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, conditional-operator

Hello Dev community I am facing an issue and need you help.

I am trying to use single button component for multiple usage and here the issue occurs.

before deeping into the issue i want to simplify my requirements as follows:

so i want to perform multiple operations based on Boolean variable **isTrue**
if this variable is true I want to print true
otherwise print false

here is the code of the file where i am trying to use the button component:

```
        
<Button            
  handleClick={`${props.openForAddUser?handleAddUser():handleUpdate()}`}           
  buttonText={`${props.openForAddUser?"Add New User":"Update"}`}
/>


function handleAddUser(){
    alert("handle add new user");
}
function handleUpdate() {
   alert("handle update");
}
```

and in case you want to understand the Button component here is the code of that component.

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <span className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <button
          
          type="submit"
          className={props.className}
          onClick={props.handleClick} // here the conditional callback function took place
        >
          {props.buttonText}
        </button>
      </span>
    </>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

**The error I am getting is like that**

```
Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
    at getListener (react-dom.development.js:4054:1)
    at accumulateSinglePhaseListeners (react-dom.development.js:9317:1)
    at extractEvents$4 (react-dom.development.js:8976:1)
    at extractEvents$5 (react-dom.development.js:9004:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9096:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:26140:1)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3991:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:9287:1)
    at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js:6465:1)
```

Note: the only solution i am looking for is to add multiple function for single onClick event.

**Solved**
Solution given by @RajBhensdadiya

the issue was that i were using backtick which converting my functions to simple string

Here is the solution

```
<Button            
  handleClick={props.openForAddUser?handleAddUser:handleUpdate}           
  buttonText={`${props.openForAddUser?"Add New User":"Update"}`}
/>
```

Comment: like an answer suggested, remove the parenthesis in the statement, so that the the function is returned instead of the funtion result.

Comment: lookup dynamic method invocation: you can do `window.a = function() {}; window["a"]();` ergo you should do something like `button[props.handleClick]()` where button is the reference to the code where your function resides. Alternative obviously to not pass the string/functionname but pass the function itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<Button            
  handleClick={props.openForAddUser ? handleAddUser : handleUpdate}           
  buttonText={props.openForAddUser ? "Add New User" : "Update"}
/>

function handleAddUser(){
    alert("handle add new user");
}
function handleUpdate() {
   alert("handle update");
}
```